# How to center the two cards (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

[site][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmQRP.png

hello please I want to center my two cards in the center and I don't know how to do it.

````
  <div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/v.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="width: 286px; height: 180px;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div >
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img/v.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="width: 286px; height: 180px;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmQRP.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped all your card inside a container and add the following code:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80vw; //Change the value if your want
  margin: auto;
/*   flex-direction: column; */ //Uncomment if you want the card to be in a line
}
```

In each card:

```
.card {
  flex: 1;
}
```